# Errors in Ajax Control Toolkit's JS files after upgrade?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I upgraded Ajax Control Toolkit to v15.x and have been working on cleaning up the code after doing so.  I'm running across exceptions being thrown, and VS breaks at points in the toolkit's JS files.  I'm not sure why or how.

I've already double-checked that any scripts are not referenced multiple times, as was the leading suggestion on Google, but I still haven't figured it out.

I really need some help with this, as I have two months invested in this project.  By the way, I'm using VS2013 and the project is in ASP/VB.

Here are a couple of the errors (to get the next, I've hit Continue):

> Unhandled exception at line 1647, column 38 in
>   http://localhost:50236/ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQmpVfriIlRNRich93DvwGtp67E1h_mWKZOFWLDGS9BMtlj8olqCr6zhXtNsVz0umlIymKK0GfDoqTLzNLe2YQI2ElwoX58_2MZEcEFLKjdG6fbv26oE3vanxWpdhskXpgCIAYbDVlsaWWDXPE-98sV01&t=ffffffffb53e74b8

and

> Unhandled exception at line 785, column 42 in
>   http://localhost:50236/ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQmpVfriIlRNRich93DvwGtp67E1h_mWKZOFWLDGS9BMtlj8olqCr6zhXtNsVz0umlIymKK0GfDoqTLzNLe2YQI2ElwoX58_2MZEcEFLKjdG6fbv26oE3vanxWpdhskXpgCIAYbDVlsaWWDXPE-98sV01&t=ffffffffb53e74b8
>
> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException:
>   Type Sys.Timer has already been registered. The type may be defined
>   multiple times or the script file that defines it may have already
>   been loaded. A possible cause is a change of settings during a partial
>   update.
>
> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException:
>   Type Sys.Extended.UI.BoxSide has already been registered. The type may
>   be defined multiple times or the script file that defines it may have
>   already been loaded. A possible cause is a change of settings during a
>   partial update.

Any and all help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I followed the instructions on the Ajax Control Toolkit website on "un-bundling" the scripts, and now everything works. Apparently I didn't do something right, or the instructions were wrong. More than likely, the former.